# Coq - Passing parameters to a record

Tags: record, coq

I'm having trouble in comparing elements of sets belonging to two distinct 
instances of the same record type. Consider the following record.

```
Record ToyRec := {
    X:Set;
    Labels:Set;
    r:X->Labels
}
```

Say that two objects `T1` and `T2` of type `ToyRec` form a good pair if 
for every element in `T1.(X)` there exists an element in `T2.(X)` with the 
same label.

```
Definition GoodPair(T1 T2:ToyRec):Prop := 
forall x1:T1.(X), exists x2:T2.(X), T1.(r) x1 = T2.(r) x2.
```

The problem is that I get an error saying that `T1.(r) x1` is of type `X1.(Labels)`, 
and `T2.(r) x2` is of type `X2.(Labels)`.

I understand the problem, and I imagine it could be solved if I could somehow 
declare the set Labels outside the record, and then pass it as a parameter. 
Is there a way to do this in Coq? Or what would be the most elegant way of 
defining the records I want and the property `GoodPair`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I got from your code his the following:

```
Record ToyRec {Labels : Set} := {
  X:Set;
  r:X->Labels
}.

Definition GoodPair {Labels:Set} (T1 T2 : @ToyRec Labels) : Prop :=
  forall x1: X T1, exists x2: X T2, r T1 x1 = r T2 x2.
```

By having `Labels` as a dependency for `ToyRec` you can be sure that both records are using the same type.

PS: I used `{Labels : Set}` instead of `(Labels : Set)` to specify that this argument is implicit and should be inferred whenever possible.